# org-mode custom agenda view with multiple lines per item?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

Is it possible to create an agenda view that displays a few lines for each item? I want to get items tagged `:project:`, by running a search like you do with `org-tags-view` (the tag and maybe some other things to narrow it further). Then for each project I want to display something like the usual header line, as well as some text below it. The text will pull from a certain item nested under the `:project:` item.

The purpose of this is that I want to see a summary of projects along with their short vision sentence that describes the positive outcome.

Comment: Do you mean something like `M-x org-agenda-entry-text-mode`?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about that. Yeah, something like that. I will look into the code and see if I can tweak it to do what I want. I'd like to see the text of a specific sub-item, as opposed to the first N lines as it's doing. But that's close.